# Wave equation under Galilean transformation

Tags: mathematical-physics, transformation, electromagnetism, special-relativity

In Jackson's book on classical electrodynamics (3rd ed, ch 11, p. 516), he mentions how a wave equation for a field $\psi(\bf{x}^{'},t^{'})$ is transformed under Galilean shift, defined as $\mathbf{x}^{'}=\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{v}t$ and $t^{'}=t$, from a the frame $K'$ to the frame $K$ as

$$ \text{In frame $K'$: } \left(  \sum\limits_{i}\frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial x^{'2}_{i}} - \frac{1}{c^{2}}\frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial t^{'2}}\right)\psi=0$$

$$ \text{In frame $K'$: } \left(  \nabla^{2} - \frac{1}{c^{2}}\frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial t^{2}} - \frac{2}{c^{2}}\mathbf{v}\cdot\mathbf{\nabla}\frac{\partial}{\partial t} -\frac{1}{c^{2}}\mathbf{v}\cdot\mathbf{\nabla v}\cdot\mathbf{\nabla}\right)\psi=0$$

How was this latter equation derived?

Answer (score 0):

The critical observation is that in the new coordinates, $\mathbf{x'}$ depends on $t$ and this needs to be taken into account in the $t$ derivatives.  For example, to compute the first partial of $\psi$ with respect to $t$, we need to look at the following:
$$ \begin{align}
\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \psi(\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{v}t, t)
&= \sum_i \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial x_i'} \frac{\partial x_i'}{\partial t} + \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial t'} \frac{\partial t'}{\partial t}\\
&= - \sum_i \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial x_i'} v_i + \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial t'} \\
\end{align} $$

I think that you can complete the calculation from there.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Another confusing point in Jackson a few pages after (p.535) is when he uses the relation: $u_{a}=2c\beta/(1+\beta^{2})$ with $\beta=v/c$, to conclude that $(1+\beta^{2})/(1-\beta^{2})=1/\sqrt{1-u^{2}_{a}/c^{2}}$. I am not sure what I am missing here. Any ideas on how he got this?

Comment: This is just an algebraic relation.  If you substitute the definition of $u_a$ into the right side of the second equation, you get $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{4 \beta^2}{(1+\beta^2)^2}}}.$$  Multiply the top and bottom by $(1 + \beta^2)$ to get $$\frac{1 + \beta^2}{\sqrt{(1+\beta^2)^2 - 4 \beta^2}} = \frac{1 + \beta^2}{\sqrt{(1-\beta^2)^2}} = \frac{1 + \beta^2}{1 - \beta^2},$$ since the quantity under the root must be positive.  You probably just made an algebra mistake somewhere.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, when we do it backwards like this, it seems simple. But how would you think of doing it starting from the definition of $u_{a}$ and wanting to find $(1+\beta^{2})/(1-\beta^{2})$, without prior knowledge of the final result?

Comment: Oh, I understand what you were asking. I am not sure. I don’t have a chance to go read that section now, but I think $u_a$ might have physical meaning, so the choice isn’t arbitrary. And since there is only one independent variable here ($\mathbf{v}$), then you are guaranteed that the other variables defined in terms of it ($\beta$ and $u_a$) will have some kind of algebraic relation to one another. Finding a nice form for it involves some exploration.